# Homeomorphism between open unit disk and complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Can I found a Homeomorphism between open unit disk and complex plane?
I already proved "the complex plane is conformal to a simply connected region", but I don't know if this is useful. Can anyone give a hint?

Comment: By homeomorphism do you mean continuous with continuous inverse? Or do you want analytic?

Comment: I mean continuous with continuous inverse

Answer (score 6):

Consider

$$f(re^{i\theta})=\dfrac{re^{i\theta}}{1-r}.$$

Its inverse is

$$g(re^{i\theta})=\dfrac{re^{i\theta}}{1+r}.$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714078)

Comment: @zar Why is not an answer? It is an explicit homeomorphism. It is only necessary to check that.

Comment: I think that an answer should be complete, not only a hint.

Comment: @zar Have you read the question? "Can anyone give a hint?"

Comment: @zar It's *very* common to just give hints, especially if the OP asks for it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Find a homeomorphism $\phi:[0,1) \to [0, \infty)$ and then define
$$f\left(R(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\right)= \phi(R) \left(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to stretch up to infinity the unit disk $D$. So you want your homeomorphism $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ to act a bit like an **homogeneous dilation** $z \mapsto \lambda \cdot z$, except the factor $\lambda$ should get larger and larger as $z$ gets near the unit circle $\{z : |z| = 1\}$. So we're actually looking for $\lambda : D \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(z) \rightarrow  +\infty$ as $|z| \rightarrow 1$, to construct the homeomorphism $f(z) = \lambda(z)\cdot z$. Of course, there are many different possibilities for $\lambda$. For instance, define $\lambda(z) = \frac{1}{1- |z|}$.